# Use IndexOf within Getter/Setter (mulitdimensional) Arraylist

Tags: android, android-studio, object, arraylist, indexof

**Framework:**

Through a onClicklistener on a Recyclerview I am adding Items to a Arraylist. At the end of the day I am using the following three lines to accomblish that:

```
int typeImage = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("introcreeps", "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
mDecklist.add(new Decklist(mData.get(position).getCardImage(),typeImage, "22", mData.get(position).getCardName(), "x1");
mRViewAdapterList.setCards(mDecklist);
```

**The Problem:**

With another OnclickListener I want to edit Elements of `mDecklist`. 
I think this should be possible with

```
positionToEdit = mDecklist.indexOf(mData.get(position).getCardName());
mDecklist.set(positionToEdit, new Decklist(mData.get(position).getCardImage(),typeImage, "22", mData.get(position).getCardName(), "x2" ));
```

*I know that `positionToEdit = mDecklist.indexOf(mData.get(position).getCardName());` is obviously wrong. What kind of Object to I have to pass to find the correct position?*

**What did not work aswell:**

CardNames will be distinct in my Arraylist therefore I would like to find the position by using that. I also tried using something the whole ArraylistObject but that did not work for me eiter like:

```
positionToEdit = mDecklist.indexOf(Decklist(mData.get(position).getCardImage(),typeImage, "22", mData.get(position).getCardName(), "x1"));
```

**Further information:**

The following is the Code for my Arraylist (Decklist):
package com.example.chris.projectartifact.b_deckbuilderTap;

public class Decklist {

```
private int CardImage;
private int TypeImage;
private String Cost;
private String Name;
private String Number;


public Decklist(int cardImage, int typeImage, String cost, String name, String number) {
    /* Why is there no this. ? */
    CardImage = cardImage;
    TypeImage = typeImage;
    Cost = cost;
    Name = name;
    Number = number;
}

public Decklist(String cost, String name, String number) {
    Cost = cost;
    Name = name;
    Number = number;
}

public int getCardImage() {
    return CardImage;
}

public void setCardImage(int cardImage) {
    CardImage = cardImage;
}

public int getTypeImage() {
    return TypeImage;
}

public void setTypeImage(int typeImage) {
    TypeImage = typeImage;
}

public String getCost() {
    return Cost;
}

public void setCost(String cost) {
    Cost = cost;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return Number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    Number = number;
}
```

}

**More Information based on Post Questions:**
To give you a feeling of what I want to do I will post a screenshot of my Recyclerviews that use mData and mDecklist:
[image: RecyclerViews]

Let me explain by using the colors:

- The *orange* Recyclerview uses mData to inflate the Recyclerview. Based on a circled *green* Button in the *orange* Recyclerview we values of mData to a new Arraylist called mDecklist.
- mDecklist is than used in the green Recyclerview to create new Values, hence we can add items from the first Recyclerview(orange) to the secound Recyclerview(green)
- But It gets more a bit more complicated! When we use the Spinners in *Yellow* the *Orange* Recyclerview is **getting a totally new mData** file from a Database. **Which means the positions are (basically) overwritten.**
- **Therefore, get(position) is not sufficient!**#
- **Every mDecklist will have use the same Name as a Card in the mData (e.g. CardName is Bloodseeker, which will also be used in mDecklist). Therefore I hoped it would be possible to find the position of a Object in mDecklist by using the Name as a search reference.**

Any Help is greatly Welcome! :)

Comment: is `mData` and `mDeckList` identical ?

Comment: mData and mDecklist are two different lists. But I use the values of mData to create mDecklist. As you may see, the first value (cardImage) is also used in mData but I need it in mDecklist aswell. So no they are not identical.

Comment: Please see the edit i made in my post. It should explain the problem more eloquent. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion by Umer that not work since `mData.get(position)` (first arraylist) will never be an Object of `mDecklist`, as explained above. But I was able to find another solution to my problem:

I am **using the Getter Methods of mDecklist to resolve my problem**. Basically it all comes down to a few lines. They are not beautiful but solve my problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mDecklist.size(); i++) {
                    if (mData.get(position).getCardName().equals(mDecklist.get(i).getName())){
                        Log.e("Print Out:", mDecklist.get(i).getName());
                        Log.e("Print Out:", "That worked");
                        mDecklist.get(i).setName("we can e.g. change the name");
                    }
                }
```

Anyway thank you very much for the suggestions and reading!

Answer (score 0):

Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in `Declist` class (android studio can automatically generate). Then `mDecklist.indexOf(mData.get(position))` will return correct index ***if and only if*** `mData.get(position)` returns a `Decklist` object contained in `mDecklist`

```
class Decklist {

private int CardImage;
private int TypeImage;
private String Cost;
private String Name;
private String Number;


public Decklist(int cardImage, int typeImage, String cost, String name, String number) {
    /* Why is there no this. ? */
    CardImage = cardImage;
    TypeImage = typeImage;
    Cost = cost;
    Name = name;
    Number = number;
}

public Decklist(String cost, String name, String number) {
    Cost = cost;
    Name = name;
    Number = number;
}

public int getCardImage() {
    return CardImage;
}

public void setCardImage(int cardImage) {
    CardImage = cardImage;
}

public int getTypeImage() {
    return TypeImage;
}

public void setTypeImage(int typeImage) {
    TypeImage = typeImage;
}

public String getCost() {
    return Cost;
}

public void setCost(String cost) {
    Cost = cost;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return Number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    Number = number;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + CardImage;
    result = prime * result + ((Cost == null) ? 0 : Cost.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((Name == null) ? 0 : Name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((Number == null) ? 0 : Number.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + TypeImage;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Decklist other = (Decklist) obj;
    if (CardImage != other.CardImage)
        return false;
    if (Cost == null) {
        if (other.Cost != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!Cost.equals(other.Cost))
        return false;
    if (Name == null) {
        if (other.Name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!Name.equals(other.Name))
        return false;
    if (Number == null) {
        if (other.Number != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!Number.equals(other.Number))
        return false;
    if (TypeImage != other.TypeImage)
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Holy shit bro. Thanks, I will try to use that later. Could you please elaborate what you are doing with the hashcodes and equals? I try to read something on hashcodes will being in the bus ;)

Comment: @Christian.gruener See this [link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-search-custom-obiects-using-indexOf-in-an-ArrayList-in-Java-I-am-told-to-override-equals-and-hashCode-but-I-dont-understand-why-or-how) for detail

Comment: Hey Umer. I tried to read into what you tried to do. I have a question and an issue to raise. Firstly you are saying _(android studio can automatically create the override)_, can you please explain to me how you did that? Secoundly, the code does not work. As I tried to explain with the screenshot in my post, **mData.get(position) is never an object of mDecklist. I used mData to fill mDecklist, there every Object of mDecklist would (for e.g.) have an entry with mData.get(position).getCardName**, but they are not the same. Can you maybe give me another hint how to solve my problem please?

Comment: Hey Umer, I do not know if this is possible for you, but can you accept my answer, so this thread closes? :)

Comment: @Christian.gruener I think there will be an option under your question to close it.

Comment: Hm, do not really see an option to close it. I guess we just wait.

Comment: @Christian.gruener next to the `edit` option there is a `close` option.

Comment: Probably I do not have enough points for doing that myself :)